# Should Logic be queried on Maths SE or Philosophy SE?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

1. Where should a question on Logic be posted? How does a querier decide?
2. Or should there be a separate SE for Logic?

The questions quoted [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/19844/53259) appear admissible and suitable also for Philosophy SE?

Comment: It seems to me that you are just asking http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/19844/are-all-symbolic-logic-questions-on-topic over again, in different words.

Comment: @GerryMyerson No offense intended, but these 2 questions can be disambiguated that the above is more general. The linked question asks about eligibility on Maths SE; the above asks how to decide in the first place where to ask.

Comment: A larger issue with some questions you have written is that, although the underlying question itself is mathematical, these questions ask instead about "intuition". A good answer here may well describe the intuition as part of the mathematical answer, but a question that asks answerers to *avoid* the mathematics and only focus on intuition is not ideal for this site. The way to learn intuition, in general, is to learn it along with the mathematics, rather than instead of the mathematics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For questions where you cannot decide which forum is appropriate: post the question on one of them; if there are no answers after two weeks, then post on the other (with links in both directions).

Answer (score 6):

Questions on logic are welcome here to the extent that they are "mathematical" questions.   There is a tag [logic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/logic) which has about 8,500 questions at the moment.

Questions that are almost entirely mathematical, such as technical questions on set theory, proof theory, computability theory, model theory, etc. that would be resolved with mathematical reasoning, are very much on topic here. Of course, these questions may relate to philosophical topics, and the best answers may include these relationships in addition to the mathematics. But the main purpose of a question on this site should be mathematics, rather than philosophy.

Questions that are not amenable to mathematical techniques are not on topic here. These might include questions on pure philosophy or questions that are purely historical.

For questions that are on-topic both here and on Philosophy.SE, you will likely get very different answers on the two sites, in much the same way that logic textbooks for philosophers are different from logic textbooks for mathematicians. This does not mean, however, that the same question should be posted to both sites - that kind of "cross posting" is discouraged.